# How to write to a file from a web application in Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, web-applications, java-ee-7, netbeans-8, tomcat8

I have asked this question before and received a lot of answers within regard to how to fix the issue. However the issue still has not been repaired and I am at a loss when it comes to the right means to repair it. I am creating a java web application in Net beans using Tomcat 8 and Java EE 7. The application is a simple form application that takes a users information and writes it to a simple text file in the WEB-INF folder. However I have tried several ways to write to the text file and all but one throw an error the one that doesn't throw an error is the one that is supposed to be correct given the research and information I have found, and the great answers that I have gotten from everyone here. My problem is that none of them work. I have moved from model 1 architecture to model 2 architecture and the like and still haven't found repair. I am posting a link to my Git Repository with all of the code inside. Please if anyone can take a look at it and let me know what is going on that would be great.
[My GitHub](https://github.com/RichardDavy42/MailList3)!

```
//doPost Method from servlet
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //get parameters from the form
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    //get relative file name
    //ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/my_new_text.txt");

     //add info to text file
     User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email);
     UserIO.add(user, path);

     //Store user object in a request object
     request.setAttribute("user", user);

     //forward request and response objects to JSP page
     String url = "/display_email_entry.jsp";
     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
     dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

//UserIO class for writing to file 
package data;

import business.User;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import static java.rmi.server.LogStream.log;

/**
 *
 * @author Richard Davy
 */
public class UserIO {
    public static void add(User user, String filepath)throws IOException{

        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(filepath, true);
        String firstName = user.getFirstName();
        String lastName = user.getLastName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        try{
            writer.println(user.getEmail() + "|" + user.getFirstName() + "|" +     user.getLastName());
            System.out.print(email + "|" + firstName + "|" + lastName);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Errors" + ex);
        }finally{
            writer.flush();        
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}


15-Jun-2014 22:24:12.321 SEVERE [354]   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet   [AddToEmailList] in context with path [/MailList3] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
at data.UserIO.add(UserIO.java:22)
at email.AddToEmailList.doPost(AddToEmailList.java:89)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried and the error you get.

Comment: I've never tried to write directly to a file from a webapp (that's what databases are for), but I'm almost certain that the issue is the security system won't let you. What have you done to override the security manager to allow this operation?

Comment: ...and regardless, this information clearly belongs in a database and not some flat file. If you write the information to a DB you won't have to worry about this type of problem. There are lightweight DBs out there (for example JavaDB which already comes bundled with Java) which are easy to set up and use with tomcat/your web app.

Comment: Alvin the Code is in the GitHub Link there are several different classes and pages that would be cumbersome to put into this setting, also I would love to write it to a database I know full well how to do that, I agree that the flat file seems a bit ridiculous, but for the purposes of my education (and I am sure that somewhere someday someone will want something to do so as I have had the request before) this is a school assignment that has gone awry. I have all of the code correct to my knowledge but I still can't get anything kicking, any ideas on how I would overwrite security features

Comment: And if so which ones should I overwrite?

Comment: All you need to show is the method which tries to create and write to the file and the code that overrides the security manager. At least include the stack traces for the errors.

Comment: I'm not sure that someone will ever want this. I've been a software engineer over 20 years and a Java developer for over 15, and I've never had to do this.

Comment: Regardless of the security manager, writing to a file in the application's WEB-INF folder really doesn't make any sense, since there is no requirement that the .war file be expanded on deployment. In the case where it's not expanded, there is no 'file' to write to, since the 'directory' is inside of a compressed .war file.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: good point. Richard, the location you're trying to write to may not even exist.

Comment: Before I try to remember how to override SecurityManager, let's verify that's actually the problem. Stack traces, please!

Comment: There are no errors, at all that is the issue I am having, I have created the file in the WEB-INF folder as I was instructed by my instructor, his idea is to have us learn this before learning the databasing techniques, Database would be no issue, this is an issue, the code is as follows:

Comment: The error is in Tomcat's log file. Seek and ye shall find.

Comment: @AlvinThompson I have added the code above, I have no errors to show, I have successfully printed the output in my server log but still cant write to the file, the file hierarchy is as follows for the web folder:

Web-Pages
  |  |
  |  META-INF
  |  WEB-INF
  |     |_web.xml
  |     |_my_new_text.txt
  |
  |_display_email_entry.jsp
  |_index.html

Comment: Can you control what are the actual permissions on the `WEB-INF` directory of your real server ? But you should **never** allow a web application to write its own files : it is a major security risk. Why do not you write elsewhere ?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, I have tried writing elsewhere, I have moved it into the same directory as the servlet, I have moved it to the directory that contains the JSP's and HTML files, but I can't seem to get it to write to the file, I have even tried writing to a file outside the application and still got no response, I can get the information to print out to the output window for the Tomcat server with a simple system.out.println method but other than that I still get no output to the file

Comment: @AlvinThompson I have added the errors that I have found below the code, I found these in the tomcat output, it says that it is throwing a nullpointer exception I think that this is the error that you are looking for

Comment: And which line is *line 22* in UserIO ? You should trace or print the value or `path`, and control that neither `file` nor `writer` are null.

Comment: Okay traced out the null pointer issue and repaired it, it was a mistake on my part where I was moving the file back and forth to  different locations so I could try and get the program to work. However even after repairing the issue, now I get no errors what so ever, I have read through the entire log and have found nothing of concern. I think this brings us back to the security issue @AlvinThompson

Comment: How are you deploying the WAR? It's a fully expanded folder in Tomcat?

Comment: And while I don't see the practical usefulness it's an interesting academic question. I'll vote it up to hopefully generate more interest.

Comment: Im just doing test runs through netbeans, as I complete the code I run it and netbeans/tomcat takes care ofnthe deployment... idk if that helps but if not if you could explain to me how to find out I will definitely do so. It will be a learning experiwnce for me that I would greatly appreciate. @AlvinThompson

Comment: In that case, it's using "in place deployment", which is fine. If the file you're trying to write to doesn't yet exist, try creating an empty file with that name and see if that changes anything.

Comment: You would need to create the file in the copy of the webapp in the "dist" folder of your project IIRC. If anyone is more familiar with NetBeans in-place deployment, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ...although this depends on whether this is a new-style NetBeans project (Maven-based) or a legacy project (Ant-based). Which is it?

Comment: Its ant based, the file exists in the WEB-INF folder, I created it because initially I thought that was the issue as well, I think I am misunderstanding the dist folder part though, you are saying put the file directly into the dist folder with the .war file?

Comment: You said you fixed the `NullPointerException` issue. Could you please update your post with current code and current errors if any remains. BTW you said you are using Netbeans and Tomcat but under what platform, Windows, Linux, other ?

Comment: @Serge Bellesta I am using netbeans 8 and tomcat 8 under the windows 7 platform I will update code shortly as soon as I get off work. Oh and no errors remain, I have searched the logs up and down and have found none.

Comment: The code is the same as the above code the null pointer exception came after that post... @SergeBellesta

Comment: If you have no errors and `System.out.print` says you routine is successful, you should have written somewhere (I think I've undertood what Alvin said). You should use Windows Explorer (**not Netbeans**) to look in your project directory. As it is an ant project, you should have a `build/web directory` and under it a `WEB-INF` **containing `classes` and `lib` sub-dirs**. Look if you have not written there.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Okay so heres the lowdown... I have managed to break the cycle of error.. lol if I choose to write to a txt file on the c drive it works fine correct output and all, however the application will not write to the txt file inside the application,  I have checked the build file in the  windows explorer as well as everywhere else still cant find the data... strange to me

Comment: BTW, I realize that you do not say what is the result of `getRealPath`, it could give a clue of where the application tries to write ...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta I have printed out the path that it is being sent to, the path is always correct, that is why I am thinking that it could be a security configuration for tomcat or the web app itself I can't seem to get it to write back to itself but I can get it to write externally?

Comment: And could the app read what it pretends to have written ?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta yes I ran a test to see if the file was readable, to get the file size, to see if the file was writable and all came back with true responses and even more so a byte size of zero so I know the application is acknowledging that the file exists and is writable as well as readable it just wont send the information to the file from the application so long as the file resides within the application. Outside the application it does fine, thoughts?